# Generalize range with a changing variable

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test11()
Dim i As Integer
i = 15
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b11") = "love"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c&i") = "Hate"
End Sub
```

This code line gives error 1004. How to change this line so that I can set i to different numbers every time. The above code is just a part of long code where range is used number of times.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c&i") = "Hate"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must refer `i` outside the quotes. This is because, `VBA` assumes `i` as a part of `range` which is not the case (because `i` is not the range itself, instead `value` of i refers to an integer which is part of range). Hence, these kind of variable `substitution` must be done outside quotes (`""`)

**Try this:**

```
Sub test11()
Dim i As Integer
i = 15
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b11") = "love"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c" & i) = "Hate"
End Sub
```